# How can I plot points generated by a Verlet Integration?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

So, I have this code for Verlet Integration:

```
U[x_] := -8*(1 - x^2)/(8 + x^4)
For[t = 0; x = -10; v = 1; f = -0, 015647; t < 50, t += d; j = f;
d = 0.01;
x = x + v*d + (f*d^2)/2;
f = -U'[x];
v = v + (j + f)*d/2;
]
```

I tested it with `Print[x]` and `Print[v]` and apparently, it's working as expected. But I can't seem to plot the points in any way. I tried saving the data to an array or a list, but it just won't work.

Comment: Look up `Table` - it is a looping construct which returns a list of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
list = {};
For[t = 0; x = -10; v = 1; f = -0, 015647; t < 50, t += d; j = f;
  d = 0.01;
  x = x + v*d + (f*d^2)/2;
  f = -U'[x];
  AppendTo[list, {v, f}];
  v = v + (j + f)*d/2];
```

Then

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose @ list,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> Large,
 PlotLegends -> {"v", "f"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! So, `AppendTo` takes the especified elements and fills a list with then? Or would that be too much of a generalization?

Comment: That's correct. Just type "list" to see its contents